# NetBeans not showing all MySQL databases

Tags: mysql, netbeans

I've some databases showing at MySql command line client as in the image below:

[image: Databases in MySql command line]

But in netbeans only the databases below are showing of the same localhost:3360 used by MySql command line client:

[image: NetBeans showing the database]

Why all of my databases are not showing in netbeans?

Comment: Either you are connecting to a different mysql instance or the mysql account netbeans uses does not have access to list all databases.

Comment: Same or different user? Have the missing databases been created after you first opened the server in NetBeans?

Answer (score 0):

NetBeans uses the same `show databases` command to load the list of databases to the database explorer. You can see the source code for it [here](https://github.com/apache/netbeans/blob/c084119009d2e0f736f225d706bc1827af283501/ide/db.mysql/src/org/netbeans/modules/db/mysql/impl/MySQLDatabaseServer.java#L97).

The `show databases` command only shows you those databases for which you have some kind of [privilege](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-databases.html).

> You see only those databases for which you have some kind of
> privilege, unless you have the global SHOW DATABASES privilege. You
> can also get this list using the mysqlshow command.

So, ether NetBeans connects to a different MySQL server or you use a different user within the NetBeans connection.